# How to solve $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2(y^2+1)}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I tried to solve this using the solution of a first order differential equation but I don't think this can be reduced to that form.

How to approach this problem and find $y$?

Please help.

Comment: Where did this problem come from?

Comment: If you assume $y(x)$ accepts a series expansion, then by directly solving for the coefficients it appears there is a solution with series expansion
$$
y(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (a_k + b_k\sqrt{5})x^{2k+1}
$$
where $a_k,b_k \in \pm\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{x^2-y^2}{x^2(y^2+1)}$

$\dfrac{dx}{dy}=\dfrac{x^2(y^2+1)}{x^2-y^2}$

With reference to http://science.fire.ustc.edu.cn/download/download1/book%5Cmathematics%5CHandbook%20of%20Exact%20Solutions%20for%20Ordinary%20Differential%20EquationsSecond%20Edition%5Cc2972_fm.pdf#page=180:

Let $u=\dfrac{x}{y}$ ,

Then $x=yu$

$\dfrac{dx}{dy}=y\dfrac{du}{dy}+u$

$\therefore y\dfrac{du}{dy}+u=\dfrac{y^2u^2(y^2+1)}{y^2u^2-y^2}$

$y\dfrac{du}{dy}=\dfrac{y^2(y^2+1)u^2}{y^2(u^2-1)}-u$

$y\dfrac{du}{dy}=\dfrac{y^2((y^2+1)u^2-u(u^2-1))}{y^2(u^2-1)}$

$\dfrac{du}{dy}=\dfrac{y((y^2+1)u^2-u(u^2-1))}{y^2(u^2-1)}$

Let $v=y^2$ ,

Then $\dfrac{du}{dy}=\dfrac{du}{dv}\dfrac{dv}{dy}=2y\dfrac{du}{dv}$

$\therefore2y\dfrac{du}{dv}=\dfrac{y((y^2+1)u^2-u(u^2-1))}{y^2(u^2-1)}$

$2\dfrac{du}{dv}=\dfrac{(v+1)u^2-u(u^2-1)}{v(u^2-1)}$

$(u^2v+u^2-u(u^2-1))\dfrac{dv}{du}=2(u^2-1)v$

$\left(v-u+1+\dfrac{1}{u}\right)\dfrac{dv}{du}=2\left(1-\dfrac{1}{u^2}\right)v$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

Let $w=v-u+1+\dfrac{1}{u}$ ,

Then $v=w+u-1-\dfrac{1}{u}$

$\dfrac{dv}{du}=\dfrac{dw}{du}+1+\dfrac{1}{u^2}$

$\therefore w\left(\dfrac{dw}{du}+1+\dfrac{1}{u^2}\right)=2\left(1-\dfrac{1}{u^2}\right)\left(w+u-1-\dfrac{1}{u}\right)$

$w\dfrac{dw}{du}+\left(1+\dfrac{1}{u^2}\right)w=2\left(1-\dfrac{1}{u^2}\right)w+2u-2-\dfrac{4}{u}+\dfrac{2}{u^2}+\dfrac{2}{u^3}$

$w\dfrac{dw}{du}=\left(1-\dfrac{3}{u^2}\right)w+2u-2-\dfrac{4}{u}+\dfrac{2}{u^2}+\dfrac{2}{u^3}$