# Solution for $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{y^2}-\frac{1}{x^2}$, change of variables, integrating factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

I encountered the following nonlinear 1st order ODE as a simplified case of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/845035/269624).

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{y^2}-\frac{1}{x^2}$$

I didn't find it in the literature and Wolfram Alpha couldn't solve it either.

However, I believe it might have a solution,.

Replace:

$$y= r \sin t, \qquad x=r \cos t$$

After simplifications, this leads to the following ODE:

$$(r^2 \sin^3 t \cos^2 t+\sin^2 t \cos t- \cos^3 t) dr+\left(r^3 \sin^2 t \cos^3 t+r( \sin t \cos^2 t-\sin^3 t) \right)dt=0$$

$$P(r,t) dr+Q(r,t)dt=0$$

Checking if the new ODE is exact or not, we find that it's not, but the partial derivatives look promising:

$$P_t =r^2 (3 \sin^2 t \cos^3 t-2 \sin^4 t \cos t) +5 \sin t \cos^2 t-\sin^3 t$$

$$Q_r =r^2 (3 \sin^2 t \cos^3 t) +\sin t \cos^2 t-\sin^3 t$$

I feel like there's a simple integrating factor we can use here, but I have no idea what it is.

---

> Can we find an integrating factor which makes the last ODE exact? If we can, what is it?
>
> Is there another way to obtain an explicit or implicit solution for the titular ODE in terms of known functions?
>
> What about the more general case ($a,b$ - constants)? $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{a}{y^2}-\frac{b}{x^2}$$

**Edit**

Multiplying by $\frac{1}{\cos^2 t}$ we obtain:

> $$\left(r^2 \sin^3 t +\frac{\sin^2 t }{\cos t}- \cos t\right) dr+\left(r^3 \sin^2 t \cos t+r\left( \sin t -\frac{\sin^3 t}{\cos^2 t}\right) \right)dt=0$$

Now we have:

$$P_t=3 r^2 \sin^2 t \cos t+ \sin t +\frac{\sin^3 t }{\cos^2 t}$$

$$Q_r=3 r^2 \sin^2 t \cos t+ \sin t -\frac{\sin^3 t }{\cos^2 t}$$

It's *almost* exact. Did I make a mistake somewhere? Or do we need a more elaborate integrating factor?

**Edit 2**

Hyperbolic substitution:

$$y= r \sinh t, \qquad x=r \cosh t$$

leads to a similar equation, which is still not exact:

> $$\left(r^2 \sinh^3 t-\frac{1}{\cosh t} \right) dr+\left(r^3 \sinh^2 t \cosh t-r \frac{\sinh t}{\cosh^2 t} \right) dt=0$$

$$P_t=3 r^2 \sinh^2 t \cosh t +\frac{\sinh t }{\cosh^2 t}$$

$$Q_r=3 r^2 \sinh^2 t \cosh t -\frac{\sinh t }{\cosh^2 t}$$

Comment: you can write $$y'(x)=\frac{(x-y(x))(y(x)+x)}{x^2y(x)^2}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, thank you, but what should I do then?

Comment: One integrating factor that is surprisingly versatile is $\mu=x^ny^m$. You might try that.

Comment: @AdrianKeister, thank you, but I tried and it doesn't work here

Comment: Another option is to try $\mu=f(x^n,y^m)$, but that can sometimes lead to a pde that's no easier to solve than the original.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

With reference to http://science.fire.ustc.edu.cn/download/download1/book%5Cmathematics%5CHandbook%20of%20Exact%20Solutions%20for%20Ordinary%20Differential%20EquationsSecond%20Edition%5Cc2972_fm.pdf#page=180:

Let $u=\dfrac{y}{x}$ ,

Then $y=xu$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=x\dfrac{du}{dx}+u$

$\therefore x\dfrac{du}{dx}+u=\dfrac{1}{x^2u^2}-\dfrac{1}{x^2}$

$x\dfrac{du}{dx}=\dfrac{1-u^2}{x^2u^2}-u$

$x\dfrac{du}{dx}=\dfrac{1-u^2-x^2u^3}{x^2u^2}$

Let $v=x^2$ ,

Then $\dfrac{du}{dx}=\dfrac{du}{dv}\dfrac{dv}{dx}=2x\dfrac{du}{dv}$

$\therefore2x^2\dfrac{du}{dv}=\dfrac{1-u^2-x^2u^3}{x^2u^2}$

$2v\dfrac{du}{dv}=\dfrac{1-u^2-u^3v}{u^2v}$

$(u^3v+u^2-1)\dfrac{dv}{du}=-2u^2v^2$

$\left(v+\dfrac{1}{u}-\dfrac{1}{u^3}\right)\dfrac{dv}{du}=-\dfrac{2v^2}{u}$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.